# Resource group location error on basic Azure pipeline release

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps, azure-devops

I'm new to Azure and trying to run an out-of-the-box pipeline on Azure but it's failing on the deployment step of the pipeline. I get the error below. I am using the free trial tier of Azure.

I have a resource group in West Europe and I have the release step of the pipeline configured to West Europe. Is there some setting on I have completely missed?

> 2020-04-10T18:08:42.8286287Z ##[error]Unauthorized: {
>     "Code": "Unauthorized",
>     "Message": "This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU.",
>     "Target": null,
>     "Details": [
>       {
>         "Message": "**This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU**."
>       },
>       {
>         "Code": "Unauthorized"
>       },

Comment: Same issue, I dont seem to be able to start any app services at all because of this

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you what the problem is:

```
This region has quota of 0 instances for your subscription. Try selecting different region or SKU
```

You do not have any quota for whatever it is you are trying to deploy. You will need to raise support request to have the quota increased in that region.

That said, if you do have quota, this could also be down to the current throttling of creating new resources in regions hit with high demand due to Covid-19. If that is the case you can try another region or wait.

Comment: Is it possible to see a region quota for a subscription?

Comment: Yes, if you go the subscriptions resource, and then select the subscription you want to look at. You should see a quota tab. You will then need to look for the resource type and region to see what you have allocated.

Comment: I can only see Storage Accounts in the quotas page. Does this mean i have 0 for everything else, or is Azure just turd?

Comment: Is storage the only option in the "select a provider" drop down on the quota page?